# How to prevent date auto-generation on chart Axis

Tags: c#, date, charts, datasource, axis

I have a function that build chart according to selected time range. 
The onClick function determinate stored procedure and data source parameters, make makes DataBind() and calls to showChartSum() function
[Stored procidure output in case of week range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDpmD.png)
Need to set d_date as AxisX and the other values as AxisY
Code:

```
public void showChartSum()
{
    DataTable dt_data;
    DataView dv_data;
    string error_message;
    int  range_id;
    chart_sum.Visible = true;
    chart_avg.Visible = false;

    range_id = int.Parse(rbl_display02.SelectedValue);
    dv_data = (DataView)sds_report.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
    dt_data = dv_data.ToTable("DTData", false, "d_date", "tip", "deposit", "compensation", "salary");
    if (dt_data.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dt_data = validateMaxChartInput(dt_data);
        chart_sum.DataSource = dt_data;
        chart_sum.Series["series_tip"].XValueMember = "d_date";
        chart_sum.Series["series_tip"].YValueMembers = "tip";
        chart_sum.Series["series_deposit"].XValueMember = "d_date";
        chart_sum.Series["series_deposit"].YValueMembers = "deposit";
        chart_sum.Series["series_compensation"].XValueMember = "d_date";
        chart_sum.Series["series_compensation"].YValueMembers = "compensation";
        chart_sum.Series["series_compensation"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart_sum.Series["series_salary"].XValueMember = "d_date";
        chart_sum.Series["series_salary"].YValueMembers = "salary";
        chart_sum.Series["series_salary"].Color = Color.SaddleBrown;
        //chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        switch (range_id)
        {
            case 1:
                //chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/M/yyyy";
                chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 500;
                break;
            case 2:
                //chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "M/yyyy";
                chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 2000;
                break;
            case 3:
                //chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy";
                chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 4000;
                break;
        }
        chart_sum.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
        chart_sum.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        error_message = "הנתונים עבור הטווח הנבחר לא קיימים במערכת";
        this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(fn.createCustomMessage(error_message));
        pnl_chart.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

The date values are not based on data source, its auto generated according to specified interval.
[Chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l9vI.png)
When i comment the interval as sagested by TaW, I get the following output in case of week (fine except of leading and closing labels)
[image: Week range chart]
In case of month the labels somehow generated with two weeks interval 
[image: Month range chart]
Please advise how to display date on chart AxisX as it appear in DataSource and not auto-generated values.

Comment: How about __not__ setting the Interval? The default is automatic and should display one per datapoint.

Comment: Thank you TaW for the replay! without interval it looks almost fine except of  displaying leading and closing label (image attached to the question) . The issue is that same  function displaying different time ranges (week, month and year) Full function code updated. Without interval in case of month, it somehow generats labels with two weeks interval. In case of year it also going wrong ...